# Why shouldn't I encapsulate some entity framework setup in a small abstract base class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, repository

I'm working with Entity Framework 4.0 and I've structured an abstract base class like this

```
 public abstract class RepositoryBase : IDisposable
{
    protected MyContext context;

    protected RepositoryBase ()
    {
        context = new MyContext();
        context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        context.CommandTimeout = int.MaxValue;
    }

    public virtual int Save()
    {
        return context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        context.Dispose();
    }

    ~RepositoryBase()
    {
        Dispose();
    }
}
```

But I'm getting increasingly nervous because I've never seen anyone doing this.  I'm doing this in a web app and creating/disposing my objects on every request (not getting into any issues with the lack of thread safety/ static variables)

I'm still creating a new ObjectContext VERY often but avoid having to attach/detach entities if if I have a class encapsulating the state of several entities.

My question : Why not just allow the ObjectContext live for the lifetime of classes which derive a class like this?

None of these objects are being put into the session or anything like that so what's the anti-pattern here?

Also, I've looked into being able to mock my ObjectContext.  I'm not convinced it's better than an in-memory database with Integration tests (Not that I still couldn't do it with a an abstract base class like this--but I'm not interested in this for this post)

Comment: Do remove the `~RepositoryBase() { }`. It is expensive but has no use.

Comment: Ah, I believe I know what you are trying to accomplish.  Try reading about the UnitOfWork Pattern.  Here would be a good start (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx).

Comment: No, too long. Use google. Just avoid destructors, you will probably never need one.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands right now your wrapper does not seem to be very useful because it really doesn't do much (unless you omitted code). I mean there's nothing wrong with it, but I wouldn't see the point if all it does is save. I think what you're looking for here is called a *repository* pattern, which is a good thing to layer on top of EF4 in most cases. If you google for "repository pattern entity framework" you'll find quite a few examples of how to implement the pattern, including full-fledged examples with generic typing (for working with concrete EF entity types) and whatnot. [This](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/01/20/using-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework.aspx) is a good, simple start.

Comment: EF _already_ implements the repository pattern. Layering one on top of it is **not** good practice.

Comment: I said in the bottom of my post I have no interest in creating a repository on top of entity framework.  Perhaps I should have specified, the point of the class is to just save the rewriting of the initialization of the context, the save method and writing the finalizer.

Comment: @Oded yes, but sometimes an abstraction on top of it is useful for things like unit testing, mocking, etc. EF implements just a _type_ of repository, it doesn't mean it's the correct one. The great thing about frameworks like EF is that you can mold them to your usage patterns fairly easily.

Comment: @brian sorry I misunderstood, but you did not mention that anywhere in your post. As to your specific need (if I understand correctly now), simply operating your ObjectContext in a `using(x) { ... }` block will be enough to handle lifetime issues. Perhaps you're looking for the UoW pattern, as another person mentioned.